# is it possible to get a left join list out a linq query

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have this reference setup

```
public class Account
{
    Guid ID {get;set;}
    string name {get;set}
}
public class Order
{
    Guid ID {get;set;}
}
public class AccountOrder
{
    Guid ID {get;set}
    Guid AccountID {get;set}
    Guid OrderID {get;set}
}

Now when I want to model this setup as so:
public class AccountOrderModel
{
    //One account with many orders 
    string name {get;set}
    List<Order>orders {get;set;}
}
```

I would like to use Linq to get the 1 account with all of the orders based on the account-order reference.

Comment: Which LINQ flavor is this? And haven't you got navigation properties like `Account.AccountOrders` etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I previously posted code which was not a proper left-outer join.. It wouldnt return an account if no orders were associated. In this code that has been fixed:

```
        var aom = from a in accounts
                  join ao in accountorders on a.ID equals ao.AccountID into aoGroup
                  from aod in aoGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(new AccountOrder())
                  join o in orders on aod.OrderID equals o.ID into oGroup
                  group oGroup by a into g
                  select new AccountOrderModel() { Name = g.Key.Name, orders = g.SelectMany(x => x).ToList() };
```

It has been tested and i think i finally got it correct.

Comment: I dont think you can call ToList() in a linq query like that. Also why cant I use the into keyword? Seems like that would be more efficient. I dont think this would work.

Comment: Also I notice when running test. That if I just join accounts to the reference table and put those "into" a result it works fine, but when I join again on the actual order table it only brings back 1.

Comment: @user516883 You can call ToList() in an Linq-to-objects query. Not in Linq-to-sql or Linq-to-entities.

Comment: @user516883, I have updated and tested the code and it works properly with my new edit.

Comment: Thanks let me give that a try. Also I noticed you said not the most efficient approach. What approach would you take. Because when you use CodeFirst and for example have an Account on an order object. It creates a Table that reference the two entities.

Comment: Also with this if I had more properties on Account how would I pull it out. For example the id or last name etc?

Comment: @user516883: I just gave you another answer using joins. Please update your question in regards to the "more properties on account" with some code examples of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @caesay: This is not left join. You should also list the accounts which dont have any orders associated - account name with empty orders list in final answer. This is not happening. Can you please take care of it?